# module 'jax' has no attribute 'xla' in Alphafold2 colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, jax

I'm trying to use Alphafold2 and keep getting these errors:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-74c943a59072> in <cell line: 55>()
     58     runner = cf_af.prep_model_runner(opt, old_runner=runner)
     59   else:
---> 60     runner = cf_af.prep_model_runner(opt)
     61 else:
     62   runner = None

________________________________________
7 frames
________________________________________
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/jax/_src/deprecations.py in getattr(name)
     51       warnings.warn(message, DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
     52       return fn
---> 53     raise AttributeError(f"module {module!r} has no attribute {name!r}")
     54 
     55   return getattr

AttributeError: module 'jax' has no attribute 'xla'
```

I was able to successfully get a protein model on my first attempt then started getting the errors.

I made sure my Python version (3.11.4) was up to date and that I have the proper versions of jax (0.4.14) and haiku (0.0.5).
It then started working again and modelled three different structures however the errors came back and I haven't been able to get it to work again. 

I also tried to do a different version of jax as suggested by someone else here but when I put in:
`pip install "jax<=0.3.16" "jaxlib<=0.3.16"`

I got:

```
Using cached jax-0.3.16-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jaxlib<=0.3.16 (from versions: 0.4.13, 0.4.14)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jaxlib<=0.3.16
```

I'm a biochemist not a programmer so I really don't know how to proceed from here. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

`jax.xla` has been deprecated and moved to `jax.interpreters.xla` as of JAX version 0.4.14 (see [JAX 0.4.14 CHANGELOG](https://github.com/google/jax/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#jax-0414-july-27-2023)).

If you have control of the code that references `jax.xla`, you should change it to `jax.interpreters.xla`.

If you do not have control of the code that references `jax.xla`, you should install jax version 0.4.13 or older for use with this code. You can do this in Colab by running:

```
!pip install jax[cpu]==0.4.13
```

if you need to install the older version with GPU support, see [JAX README: pip installation – GPU](https://github.com/google/jax#pip-installation-gpu-cuda-installed-locally-harder).

Comment: I added:  !pip install jax[cpu]==0.4.13                                                                                                                            
as the first line of the section of the Colab where the error keeps popping up.
Now I get:

---> 56   assert isinstance(axis, collections.Iterable), (
     57       'axis needs to be either an iterable, integer or "None"')
     58 
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'

Comment: Then you probably need a different jax version. I'd consult the documentation for the package you're trying to use to figure out which JAX version it expects, and then use that version.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively `pip install dm-haiku==0.0.11`

I got this error after I installed colabfold in a non-standard way (I wanted CPU-only for a large and low priority job which wasn't worth the `XLA_PYTHON_CLIENT_MEM_FRACTION` faff), namely

```bash
export PYTHONUSERBASE=$HOME2/waconda/envs/colabfold2CPU
conda update -n base conda -y
conda create -n colabfold2CPU python=3.10 &&
conda activate colabfold2CPU &&
conda env config vars set PYTHONUSERBASE=$CONDA_PREFIX
conda install ipykernel
conda install git
conda install -c conda-forge openmm==7.7.0 pdbfixer -y
$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/python -m pip install --no-warn-conflicts "colabfold[alphafold-minus-jax] @ git+https://github.com/sokrypton/ColabFold" tensorflow-cpu==2.12.0
$CONDA_PREFIX/bin/python -m -m pip install jax==0.3.25 chex==0.1.6 biopython==1.79
cd ${CONDA_PREFIX}/lib/python3.10/site-packages/colabfold
sed -i -e "s#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt#import matplotlib\nmatplotlib.use('Agg')\nimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt#g" plot.py
sed -i -e "s#appdirs.user_cache_dir(__package__ or \"colabfold\")#\"${COLABFOLDDIR}/colabfold\"#g" download.py
```

Somehow `jaxlib` was `0.4.20`, yet I pip installed `jax==0.3.25` so I tried my luck with `pip install jax -U`. Then got the above error. In the full trace, haiku (the old ersatz Sonnet for jax, which has since been replaced by `flax`) was the problem. `pip install dm-haiku -U` brought my version from `dm-haiku-0.0.9` to `dm-haiku-0.0.11` and colab works now.